# Next JS API calls with auth0

Tags: next.js, auth0

I have a question about **auth0** and **next js**.

For example, I have the next code (this code works)

```
//initialprops enables server-side rendering in a page and allows you to do initial data population
ModelsList.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  //this is static token to test from auth0.com
  const accessToken = 'eyJhbG.....'
  //fetching data
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:7071/api/bo/getModels', {
   headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
   }
  })
    
  const json = await res.json()
   
  return { data: json }
}
```

As you can see, I have accessToken variable as a text. It's a problem for me

How can make **accessToken** dynamic?

Thanks a lot!

P.S please, dont reference to auth0 documentation, I have tried a lot. Provide, please, a real solution/example.

Comment: And where would the `accessToken` come from if you were to make it dynamic?

Comment: Really don't know, in the documentation they have this example: https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/main/examples/kitchen-sink-example/pages/api/shows.ts

But if you test example, you have and Object error (cannot handle Response).
Can you please provide some examples?

Comment: Keep in mind that your code runs inside `getInitialProps` - which can run both on the server and on the client - while the example you linked is in an API route which always happens on the server. You may want to try using `getServerSideProps` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this is what worked for me.

Let's say you've got `api.example.com/resources`. This where data actually is. You will need to proxy via next's api.

Inside your jsx component, you fetch next's api.

```
// components/Dashboard.jsx

const API_URL = "api/resources"; 

async function fetcher(url: any) {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const json = await res.json();
  return json;
}

function Dashboard() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(API_URL, fetcher);

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>;

  return <div>show your resources here</div>;
}
```

and now inside the next's api file you can fetch the actual endpoint you need.

```js
// api/resources.js
import {
  getAccessToken,
  getSession,
  withApiAuthRequired,
} from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";

export default withApiAuthRequired(async function healthcheck(req, res) {
  const session = await getSession(req, res);
  const token = session?.idToken;

  const response = await fetch("https://api.example.com/resources", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

if you get errors, check the jwts you're getting. Audience or scope mismatch errors are usually the main culprits.

Comment: Why you have to call your external api via next's api file? Is it something wrong to call it directly from a page file via ie. fetch()?

What if my app authenticate with auth0 through regular auth0 react sdk?

Comment: @JanTestowy did you ever figure out what the advantage of using the NextJS api as a proxy was?

Comment: The problem is that getAccessToken(req, res) requires the request and the response, and you have not those objects at the clienet level. 

I think is no ta problem of useSWR, or fetch, is basically that the data is being fetched/posted in the client 

I also was looking to authenticate from the fetcher but didn't find a way to pass the req, res objects that carries already data from the the auth0 authentication.
For now having the /pages/api/ and use them as proxy is the solution i found.